# Batch rename and compress (combining separate working commands- .ps1 & .bat)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, batch-processing

I figured out how to batch-rename files in a directory to my liking using powershell:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\s\((.*)",$_.extension}
```

I also figured out how to batch-compress each file using the command prompt:

```
for %%X in (*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%X.zip" "%%X"
```

I'd like to combine these two operations in a single .ps1 or .bat but am unsure how to proceed. (i.e. rename, then compress each file individually).

Answer (score 0):

I have this archiving command from Powershell, try to insert it in the example  above

```
& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "d:\1.zip" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\readme.txt"
```